# The Application full path is working with Windows Explorer, but not from batch file

Tags: batch-file

ECHO Open IWS ,

Start "" "C:\Users\zteohx\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\4NQ770YE.NOA\4ZJ8B8TR.DZC\inte..tion_0000000000000000_032d.0001_d7bd60f44abeb81d\InteractionWorkspace.exe"

getting error:
IWS has stopped working.
A problem caused the program  to stop working correctly.
Windows will close the program and notify if a solution is available.
/Close program.

Please help

Comment: It would seem that IWS has a problem, the start command is working as it should.  Try shortening the path to the exe file as a test.

Comment: Try it without the start just the path in quotes. it is unreliable but it may still work.

Comment: IWS work in exe format.

Comment: 09stephenb triad but not work